# Deploying a Bot in On Premises Ms Teams server

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am  building a bot with the Microsoft Bot Framework using node.js and so far testing with emulator, now i need to deploy my bot to on premises MS Teams server. What are the necessary steps before the deployment

Comment: Microsoft Teams is a cloud only product, do you want to deploy your bot to an on premises Skype for Business / Lync server? Could you clarify your question.

Comment: Hi @Mick, Sorry for the confusion, I need to deploy my bot in skype for business server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skype for Business bots can be connected to the Skype for Business Server users if hybrid connectivity has been deployed in the environment. [(documentation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skype-for-business-bot-framework/docs/bot-hybrid-support) [Supported Skype for Business versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skype-for-business-bot-framework/docs/overview#supported-skype-for-business-versions)

Please not that the Skype for Business Bot Framework channel is still in Developer Preview and really limited compared to other channels. Not everything which is possible in the emulator (like cards and buttons) is possible on the Skype for Business channel.

Comment: AS per current requirement, I need to deploy my Bot in MS Teams. I am completely new to Bot development/Framework. I have only on JS file for Bot and another python file acting as APi for js file.  Could you please help me on this.

Comment: @kamarajMuthupandian this is out of scope for this question and I would recommend to have a look at [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) first.